# Need help identifying masonry wall composition

Tags: walls, brick, masonry

I have a British house dating from the 1890s to 1940s - it was partially destroyed by a rocket in the war, so some bits are old and some are new. I am trying to identify the composition of an internal wall.

This is the wall in question:

[image]

Specifically I am trying to work out what the section of grey material is. The grey material seems quite hard: harder than mortar and approximately as hard as brick. It's about 30mm thick.

The overall thickness of the wall is about 180mm and the centre of the wall appears to a single layer of standard red brick.

Comment: That looks a lot like concrete to me.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58826/old-brick-foundation-walls-125-years-need-repointing-and-or-plaster-finish-wh

Comment: Probably lime based. Unless someone did some work in the last hundred years and they used portland where they shouldn't. You're supposed to take a sample somewhere... What's the objective here anyway?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was rather fluid at one time. Maybe “grout”.